# Assign leads from few queues as per round robin rule

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

In my org i have Lead assignment rule set and working. In that rule i have assigned leads to various queues depending on some field values.

But i was trying to distribute leads from few queues to its members evenly according to round robin rule, but haven't found any proper solution ...yet.

So to sum up: I want current assignment rule work as it is but leads from some of the queues to be redistributed to its members equally. anybody have faced this situation in past and know any solution, pls let me know :) 
eg. My assignment rules will send leads to all queues que1, que2, que3. i want to distribute leads from que2 to its members.

Comment: so, if you have two queues, Queue0 and Queue1, with  5 and 10 members, respectively, you want 1/3 of incoming leads to go to Queue 0 and 2/3 of the incoming leads to go to Queue1?

Comment: No. I have updated my question with example.

Comment: Your example is still unclear

Comment: ok. I have asked on more question on stackexchange : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/equally-distribute-leads-from-a-queue     This will help you...Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can look for the options to use **Omni-Channel for lead assignment**.

> Use Omni-Channel to create work items from Salesforce records and route them to the most qualified, available agents in your organization. That’s right: You can automatically route most Salesforce objects in a Salesforce Queue—including cases, leads, chats, and SOS video calls—to your agents.
>
> With Omni-Channel, you can set the priority of work items to make sure that critical assignments get taken care of quickly. You can manage your agents’ capacity and availability for work to ensure that they’re given only the number of assignments that they can handle. You can also define which agents can work on different types of assignments. Best of all, agents no longer have to pick and choose work items manually from a queue, and managers no longer have to triage or dispatch work to agents. Work is served to the most qualified available agent in real time!

For more information, refer [Push Work to Qualified, Available Support Agents with Omni-Channel](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_omnichannel_announcement.htm)